# IOS print pdf in A4 Format

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uiprintinteractioncntrler

I'm trying to print a PDF from my `UIWebView`, but the output PDF does not fill the A4 format. Why? How do I resolve that?

**Any help will be greatly appreciated =)**

Comment: What it looks like? 3.5 inch? 4 inch?

Comment: It printing only the actual view. I would try to resize it.
CGRect frame = view.frame;
frame.size.height -= 800;
view.frame = frame;

Comment: does not do anything expect that my view in the phone is bigger.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155580/printing-pdf-using-airprint-causes-small-output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If **found** the solution by **avoid** printing form `IUWebView` . I **directly** download the **PDF** in **NSData** format.

*_data represente the  NSData that i download by a request.*

```
 if (_data) {
    UIPrintInteractionController *printController = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];

    printController.delegate = self;

    UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
    //printInfo.jobName = [path lastPathComponent];
    printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
    printController.printInfo = printInfo;
    printController.showsPageRange = YES;
    printController.printingItem = _data;

    void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) = ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
        if (!completed && error) {
            NSLog(@"FAILED! due to error in domain %@ with error code %lu", error.domain, (long)error.code);
        }
    };

    [printController presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
}
```